# Missing FROM-clause, Update_all posts, where comment_ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I want to update all posts, where comment IDs

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {id: comment_ids}).update_all(status: 1)
```

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments"

Comment: are you updating posts or comments? ;)

Answer (score 4):

When using `update_all` association should be loaded with `joins` instead of `includes`. Because `includes` loads associated items in another query, therefore

```
Post.joins(:comments).where(comments: {id: comment_ids}).update_all(status: 1)
```

should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
posts = Post.joins(:comments).where(comments: {id: comment_ids})
posts.update_all(status: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use inner query to identify posts which needs to be updated.

```
post_ids = Comment.where(id: comment_ids).select(:post_id) #creates query to select all posts ids
Post.where(id: post_ids).update_all(status: 1) #executes update query on all posts
```